# runtime-conditional prePostEnable in EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently using

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Is it possible to make the prePostEnabled a false at runtime based on some environment variable?

I incorrectly tried to do

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = !"${spring.profiles.include}".equals("noSecurity"))`

but then have intellij telling me that the attribute must be a constant.
I think it will work to create a custom MethodSecurityMetadataSource method but am not quite sure how to go about this or any other method that will let me change prePostEnabled at runtime